# From localhost to aurora serverless

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm studying the possibility to switch from an rds mysql (in use and with tables and data inside) to aurora serverless mysql to try to spend less money because the database is used for few operations. I can connect to rds mysql from my pc (dbeaver, mysql workbench and so on) without problems and I can design tables, view data, create users...
Now, I've created the new serverless db and attached to the same vpc and sec group of the first one but I can't connect to it from my pc. I've read on aws guides that there are two solutions:

- use ec2 to ssh tunnel requests --> but it's a payware solution;
- use cloud9 and connect via terminal --> but organizing a db in this way is not so simple as using a gui client.

For this reasons I've quite understood that serverless is not a good solution for now.
Any idea or suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want to use ssh tunnel, then your other choice is VPN, which is also not free.

Comment: I already have a vpn with internet gateway attached.

Comment: So you can't use that to access your vpc with the aurora serverless?

Comment: I successfully connect to rds mysql, but not to aurora serverless